# Deleted all Mac OS X internal hard drive partitions

Tags: macos, partition, recovery, data-recovery, recovery-hd

I booted to a live Ubuntu USB, wanting to delete partitions on an SD card, and ended up deleting all my partitions on my MacBook Pro's internal hd.

I have already tried gpart (which gets stuck at "Begin scan...") and testdisk (which can't create partitions since "Function write_part_mac not implemented"!).

I did try <kbd>cmd</kbd> + <kbd>R</kbd> at boot, but gave it up as it was taking a long time. I thought there would be an easier and faster alternative.

Is there a way to recover?

Comment: Well if you deleted everything, you can recover nothing unless you have a time machine backup. If you also deleted the recovery hd partition, you can't even reinstall the OS except via internet recovery (which you should be able to do with holding Cmd-R, not sure why it takes so long for you).

Comment: Anything newer than about 2011 should be able to use Cmd/R for recovery; needs an internet connection - alternatively, build a bootable USB on another machine. presumably your data is on a backup, if that's on Time Machine, either method will allow you to recover directly from that

Comment: Sadly, I dont' have a backup of my data. But, it wasn't very important stuff anyway... The internet recovery was taking hours to load... I have no idea why. My net connection is quite fast though.

Comment: try booting from an external HDD that has OSX on it and install OSX again through disk utility on your new formatted DISk